# Chi square value from scipy.stats has degree of freedom = 0 as default. What does this mean?

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, data-fitting

Hi I have data sets (maxwellian and gaussian) that I make a histogram plot with. I fit the data using scipy.stats.chisquare but it has by default, degrees of freedom as 0. If I understand correctly, it is not possible right?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To directly answer your question, you are correct - Degrees of freedom being 0 is invalid/useless. `scipy.stats.chisquare` parameter isn't degrees of freedom but an adjustment to degrees of freedom. Degrees of freedom defaults to `k - 1` when ddof = 0. `k` can be directly determined from the data you pass to the chisquare function.

From the [Scipy chiqsuare documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html)

> ddof : int, optional
>   “Delta degrees of freedom”: adjustment to the degrees of freedom for the p-value. The p-value is computed using a chi-squared distribution with k - 1 - ddof degrees of freedom, where k is the number of observed frequencies. The default value of ddof is 0.

`ddof` is the **delta** not the absolute value for degrees of freedom. So degrees of freedom is k - 1 and `ddof` is an adjustment subtracted from k - 1. So when ddof = 0, degrees of freedom = `k - 1 - 0` or `k - 1` . When ddof = 1, degrees of freedom = `k - 1 - 1` or `k - 2` . k is the number of observed frequencies and the `chisquare` function can determine that from the data you pass

Comment: My original comment was for the variance function. It was updated to answer the posters actual question regarding chisquare.

Comment: So if I have a total of 1000 numbers in a range 0 to 100 (just for example) that I use to create a histogram, is k = 1000? Or does k change for different bins in the histogram?

Comment: I believe k is the number of observed events in each bin(category)

Comment: Actually just realized that the axis parameter to chisquare defines the behavior. It is set to 0 by default. If you set it to None the array is flattened and k would based upon all the observations. From the docs `The axis of the broadcast result of f_obs and f_exp along which to apply the test. If axis is None, all values in f_obs are treated as a single data set. Default is 0.`

Comment: Best Comment I read that explains the ddof in detail and in plain English.